# Validate each parent intermediary is also a parent to itself

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to validate where each parent intermediary is also a parent to itself. So this query should return invalid parents in SELECT if table has any.

I need to do is first of all get all parents records. This should be done by joining `Intermediries` to itself `on ParentIntermediaryID = IntermediaryID` (inner join). Now, from all the parents return those parents that don't have any rows with `ParentIntermediaryID = IntermediaryID`.

I hope the requirement is clear. Can you give me query for this?

**Create the test table**

```
CREATE TABLE Intermediary
    (
    IntermediaryPK INT ,
    IntermediaryID NVARCHAR(20),
    IntermediaryName NVARCHAR(200),
    IntermediaryTypeID NVARCHAR(1),
    ParentIntermediaryID NVARCHAR(20),
    IntermediaryTypePK TINYINT,
    ParentIntermediaryPK INT
    GrandParentIntermediaryPK INT
    GrandParentIntermediaryID NVARCHAR(20)
    )
```

**Insert the test data into the test table**

```
INSERT INTO Intermediary
   (IntermediaryPK, IntermediaryID, IntermediaryName, IntermediaryTypeID, ParentIntermediaryID,
    IntermediaryTypePK, ParentIntermediaryPK, GrandParentIntermediaryPK, GrandParentIntermediaryID)
SELECT 552, '200244584261', 'A', '1', '201841943403', 1, 6459, 6459, '201841943403' UNION ALL
SELECT 553, '200983879092', 'B', '1', '200707895681', 1, 6462, 6459, '200707895681' UNION ALL
SELECT 554, '200925413387', 'C', '1', '200707895681', 1, 6462, 6462, '200707895681' UNION ALL
SELECT 555, '200472620781', 'D', '1', '200707895681', 1, 6462, 6462, '200707895681' UNION ALL
SELECT 556, '201902784325', 'E', '1', '200707895681', 1, 6462, 6462, '200707895681' UNION ALL
SELECT 557, '201874832909', 'F', '1', '200707895681', 1, 566 , 6462, '200707895681' UNION ALL
SELECT 558, '201264024229', 'G', '1', '200707895681', 1, 566 , 6462, '200707895681' UNION ALL
SELECT 559, '201725870455', 'H', '1', '201062751762', 1, 566 , 6462, '200707895681'
```

I have tried with this query:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    Intermediary AS I1 
WHERE   ParentIntermediaryPK IS NOT NULL 
AND     NOT EXISTS ( 
            SELECT  * 
            FROM    Intermediary AS I2 
            WHERE   I2.IntermediaryPK = I2.ParentIntermediaryPK 
            AND I1.ParentIntermediaryPK = I2.IntermediaryPK )
```

Comment: Are you looking for a condition similar to IntermediaryPK = ParentIntermediaryPK ?

Comment: Hi Praveen...Thanks for reply...
I just want to write a query which will validate each parent intermediary is also a parent to itself. Can you give me the query I will check it once....

Thanks.....

Comment: The wording of your question is too vague.  It allows multiple interpretations, which could lead to multiple mutually contradictory answers.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your required result

Comment: Hi Walter


Actually for validation I have to write query in format like: SELECT X FROM Y WHERE Z IS NULL.....to validate each parent intermediary's parent is that parent intermediary itself....

Comment: You don't make much sense. Where did you get the requirement that you *have* use `WHERE Z IS NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * 
from table 
where IntermediaryPK = ParentIntermediaryPK;
```

Or

```
Select * 
from table 
where IntermediaryID = ParentIntermediaryID;
```

Comment: Actually for validation I have to write query in format like:
SELECT X
FROM Y
WHERE Z IS NULL

Comment: Hi Praveen
Here is the sample data

intermediarypk intermediaryid parentintermediaryid parentintermediarypk grandparentintermediarypk
37 2003840093340001 NULL NULL NULL
38 200279839266 NULL NULL NULL
39 201995093279 NULL NULL NULL
40 200003615409 201951376189 4005 NULL
41 201336769172 201951376189 4005 NULL
42 201441882733 201282938485 6460 NULL
....
.....

Comment: and your desired result is what?

Comment: This query should not give any output. It should only validate each parent intermediary is also a parent to itself. foe ex. If I want to 'Validate each client has a valid gender' I hace written a query which is:

SELECT * 
FROM CLIENT
WHERE ISNULL(ClientGenderName,'') NOT IN 
(SELECT ISNULL(Gender,'') FROM PARTY_DETAILS)

So the query format will be like this for our task, and this query will not give any output, It just give column names....

Comment: I want to write validation Query which should return invalid parents I If any..